# How to disable jquery connected sortables on the go?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Given two simplest connected sortables,

**Problem (updated).** when a draggable item leaves its container, the container should not accept it back while the item is still being dragged (as if the container is disabled). On the DOM level, the placeholder should not move back to the original container.

*How can this be accomplished?*

---

The code in this [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/mcmlxxxiii/pMYft/) is not working as expected, but should be a good starting point.

Comment: at what point are you wanting to prevent the original container from accepting the draggable item?  As soon as you click to drag and it's in a dragging state or after it's been dropped to the destination and you don't want to be able to drag it back?

Comment: I'm willing to prevent the accepting while the item is still being dragged. But regardless of that, the other connected sortables should still accept the draggable item.

Comment: So what happens if we drag something out and leave it somewhere outside both sortables? It gets deleted? By the way *"When a draggable item leaves its container, the container should not accept it back while the item is still being dragged"* - that is a vague description. If the item is "being dragged" then there is no need for it to be accepted by anyone. Acceptance is an issue when an item is dropped somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will do...

http://jsfiddle.net/pMYft/15/

```
$("#origin").sortable({
    connectWith: '.destination'
}).disableSelection();
$(".destination").sortable({
    connectWith: ".destination",
}).disableSelection();
```

the origin list can drag to either of the destination lists but not back to itself.

Comment: No, that's not it too. The key point is "while dragging". Actually, none of connected sortables can get disabled while dragging with e.g. `$(this).sortable('disable')`. Neither origin, nor any other. And I'm looking for a workaround.

Comment: This is pretty tricky to do while dragging.  You need a destination for the element no matter what so if the user clicks it but drags it off screen for instance it needs to end up somewhere.  So what would be the default location if they click it but don't actually drag it to one of the other lists?

Comment: I suppose one trick may be to put an invisible div block on top of the origin container, you'd have to toy with z-indexes, but that may be the workaround.

Comment: I don't mind if it would return to the original container. Besides, the `stop` callback would be triggered on drop, which can have whatever logic with the item, or the container, or the whole DOM implemented. What would solve my problem is the callback `enter` returning false, but it doesn't exist it yet.

Comment: I've already played with zIndexes and it didn't help. The sortable just knows by cached positions that the pointer is over the container and it can't be fooled like that.

Answer (score -2):

I was working on your code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qJh9z/3/) and i changed it

```
$("ul").sortable({
    connectWith: "ul",
    items: "li:not(.ui-state-disabled)",
    cancel: "ui-state-disabled",
    out: function (e, ui) {
        ui.item.addClass("ui-state-disabled");       
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not it. The desired behaviour is that you may still drag the item over the original container, but that doesn't affect the container at all, as if it is disabled.

Comment: I give up... :( I can't. The problem is the placeholder :(